# New air-cond for Mazda MX5 Mark 1

Tags: ac, mazda, miata

I have a 1991 MAzda Miata/MX 5. The air-cond packed in a decide or more ago. Even if I could have it repaired, the CFC or whatever is almost certainly illegal nowadays (bought in Florida, currently in the UK).

Would it be possible to rip out the old air-cond system and replace it brand-new?

Comment: Anything is possible if you throw enough money at it. (Some amount of money can be substituted by labor time, but probably not all.) Beyond that, the question becomes "Is the cost (or cost and time) worth it?" which is opinion, and not appropriate for Stack Exchange.

Comment: [Take a look at this video](https://youtu.be/B1VG1OHEfAM) from Eric the Car Guy. He explains what it takes to retrofit your R12 to R134a, like you're suggesting you want to do. It is COMPLETELY doable to do this ... however, as @David suggest it depends on how much money you want to spend to get it done.